# I try to use Angular Form. But i got formControl error

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular13

I'm using angular 13

> Form

[image: 1]

> Ts File

[image: 2]

> App Module

[image: 3]

> Error

[image: 4]

[image: 5]

Comment: Please share actual code instead of images.

Comment: Please take the time to read about [asking good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define the `FormControl` in your `AboutComponent` as follows:

```
export class AboutComponent {

  name = new FormControl('');

  ...
}
```

For further details, please consult [Reactive Forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms).